# Scope of object in JSP

Tags: java, scope

I am new to Java and started exploring it a little bit.
I know this is silly question but i did not find any supporting blog or article on net which will clarify my doubt.

I want to know the scope of Java object.
Consider a scenario: Suppose i am accessing a page in browser say "index" which is using object X with some value it it and if i refresh the page can i get the previous value of object X?

If yes, how does it holds? because it all together a different request and how does it recognize that it is the same request?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this question about **Java** or **JavaScript**? Also please add code, even if basic - some line of code explain better than thousands of words what you'd like to ask...

Comment: You are talking about Java objects used in JSP pages (scriptlets) ?

Comment: may be though cookies or URL rewriting

Comment: Are you talking about maintaining a session?

Comment: @SayemAhmed: yes i am talking about JSP

Comment: @SureshKamrushi: Well, in JSPs objects have four different scopes - application, session, page and request. Try searching Google with these keywords. An additional suggestion - don't use Java objects in this manner, and completely avoid Scriptlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am heavily recommending you to read the official docs on `Object` scope.

There are four possible scopes:

> `scope="page"--`The object is accessible only from within the JSP page where it was created.
>
> `scope="request"--`The object is accessible from any JSP page servicing the same HTTP request that is serviced by the JSP page that created the object.
>
> `scope="session"--`The object is accessible from any JSP page sharing the same HTTP session as the JSP page that created the object.
>
> `scope="application"--`The object is accessible from any JSP page used in the same Web application (within any single Java virtual machine) as the JSP page that created the object.

[Here is the official docs link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97336_01/buslog.102/a83726/genlovw3.htm#1007387)

Answer (score 1):

This question is more to do with server side retention I assume when you say "if I refresh the page".  If a servlet had stored the value that was presented on the page then yes, it would still show it on the page.

If the question was based around java applets and the value had not been persisted and just entered into a textbox then no, it would not still be there.

If you want to know about object scope you might consider rephrasing your question with an example.  Most web scenarios with browsers for instance may use a framework such as Spring which is a little more complicated than just object scope.

If you want to learn more about web scope consider looking at [this oracle page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnafp/index.html) on the servlet life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can store and retrieve objects by saving them as attributes in a session (HttpSession object) using:

```
public void setAttribute(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Object value)
public java.lang.Object getAttribute(java.lang.String name)
```

For example, I can save a user's score on a multi-page quiz:

```
session.setAttribute("score", (Integer) value);
score = ((Integer) (session.getAttribute("score"))).intValue();
```

This is persistent to traversing/refreshing pages. Even though it is not the same request, it is the same session.